# Can only use .str accessor with string values when dataframe column has been converted to all strings

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract some information from a FDA webpage. I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Get CEDI html tables 
CEDI_inv_url = "https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/sda/sdNavigation.cfm?sd=edisrev&displayAll=true"

CEDI_HTML_tables = pd.read_html(CEDI_inv_url)

# STEP 2: Extract information from HTML Tables (i.e., scrapping of information)

CEDI_table_data = CEDI_HTML_tables[0]

CEDI_df = pd.DataFrame (CEDI_table_data, columns = ['MAINTERM','CAS NO','CUM DC (ppb)','CEDI','REGNUM'])

CEDI_df['CAS NO'].to_string()

CEDI_df['CAS NO'] = CEDI_df['CAS NO'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+[\u2011|-][0-9]{2}[\u2011|-][0-9](?![0-9]))')

CEDI_df.head()
```

I am getting a Can only use .str accessor with string values! error. I have tried many approaches to converting the dataframe to a string.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the column you are accessing isn't a string. Using .astype(str) should fix that:

```
import pandas as pd

CEDI_inv_url = "https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/sda/sdNavigation.cfm?sd=edisrev&displayAll=true"

CEDI_HTML_tables = pd.read_html(CEDI_inv_url)

CEDI_df = pd.DataFrame(CEDI_HTML_tables[0], columns = ['MAINTERM','CAS/ID NO','CUM DC (ppb)','CEDI (mg/kg bw/d)','REGNUM'])

CEDI_df['CAS/ID NO'] = CEDI_df['CAS/ID NO'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([0-9]+[\u2011|-][0-9]{2}[\u2011|-][0-9](?![0-9]))')

print(CEDI_df.head())
```

---

output:

```
                                            MAINTERM CAS/ID NO  CUM DC (ppb)  CEDI             REGNUM
0  (1,1,4,4- TETRAMETHYLTETRAMETHYLENE)BIS(TERT-B...       NaN           0.2   NaN  177.2600 177.1520
1  (2,4,4-TRIMETHYLPENT-2-YL)-N-PHENYL-1-NAPHTHYL...       NaN          50.0   NaN                NaN
2  (2- (METHACRYLOYLOXY)ETHYL)TRIMETHYLAMMONIUM M...       NaN           0.4   NaN   178.3520 176.170
3              (2-ALKENYL(C15-21))SUCCINIC ANHYDRIDE       NaN           5.0   NaN            176.170
4  (N-OCTYL)TIN S,S'S" TRIS(ISOOCTYLMERCAPTOACETATE)       NaN           7.7   NaN           178.2650
```

Comment: CAS number is blank.. It should not be.. Thank you though!

Comment: `CEDI_df['CAS NO'].to_string()` doesn't do anything with the result. It's not needed any more.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I just remove that from my answer. Any idea on where it's generating the NaN part?

Comment: I don't see `CAS NO` anywhere in the HTML. It's `CAS/ID NO`

Comment: @Barmar yup, just edited to reflect that. But it's still generating NaN.

Comment: Sorry, I meant CAS/ID NO..

Comment: Do you see the values if you don't use the `.astype` line?

Comment: Just reverts back to the original error OP was talking about.

Comment: Its very weird behavior.. .astype doesnt work.. Tried it with 'string', 'str, , etc..

Comment: @tom the issue is with your RegEx, can you explain to me what it's suppose to be doing?

Comment: Its supposed to splitup the string into something like this :111111-11-1 i.e. the first  set of numbers can be 2-6 digits in length and the second bunch is two digits in length and the final set is only one number in length.. Does that make sense?